# Javascript initialization with React

Tags: reactjs, materialize

Hi so I'm currently using the Materialize and React library for my project. I really want to use their Date picker which has to be initialized with the following javascript.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
   selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
   selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
});
```

where the html is represented by:

```
 <input type="date" class="datepicker">
```

http://materializecss.com/forms.html

How would I go about incorporating this into my React project. I can't seem to figure out where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery works with DOM. It finds an element, does some dirty tricks over it, and so a simple `input` element becomes a little tree with some DOM event listeners.

React builds DOM from components via *rendering* them. To make a component turn into a DOM element, React *mounts* this component to a certain point within the DOM tree. After the component has been mounted, it's accessible via old good DOM API, like `document.getElementById` and such.

React component can have `componentDidMount` property which is a function that is executed after the component has been mounted, and so it's guaranteed it's present in DOM tree.

Connecting the dots, you need to use jQuery stuff inside `componentDidMount`, like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        className="datepicker"
        onChange={event => console.log('Just changed!', event.target.value)} />
    );
  }
}
```

But a better practice is to refer to a certain DOM element via its ref (see [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)), so the code would look like

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const node = this.input;

    $(node).pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        className="datepicker"
        ref={node => {
          this.input = node;
        }}
        onChange={event => console.log('Just changed!', event.target.value)} />
    );
  }
}
```

In React, DOM is secondary and is only rendered from the underlying data represented by component state and props. The UI responds to the data updates [*reactively*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), this is why you also need to take care of updating this data, but it's out of scope of this question and is perfectly googleable.

Comment: I tried running the code above but I can't seem to get anything to spit out of onChange or onClick. Have any theories? Could the materialize javascript be preventing these listeners from working properly?

Comment: I believe this happens because the input field doesn't actually receive these events. It is very usual to jQuery since it mutates the DOM. I believe you need to look for that plugin's ways to listen to events and connect them to your component's methods.